# NTFS-3G cross-compatibility

Tags: partitioning, ntfs

I have noticed that Ubuntu reads NTFS drives (due to the NTFS-3g Driver I guess).

My question is: how safe is it to write files to the NTFS volume while in Ubuntu's Live CD? Are all the read/write operations safe and transparent?

The question may be dumb, but I want to make sure. I would like to install Ubuntu on a partition and leave the other NTFS partitions that I have as they are. I have data on them and I cannot move it at the moment.

Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Generally yes.
Newest versions see chkdsk flag and will not let you mount it and see the hibernation flag and will not let you mount it either. But do not use hibernation if dual booting.

Best not to write a lot into Windows system partition or c: drive. Read is fine. It is more that the Linux NTFS driver exposes all the hidden files & folders that Windows hides. So you can have accidents. I used to always change Windows to show hidden files and learned how to fix it after moving or deleting something I should not have.

Always a good idea to have a shared NTFS data partition or d: drive in Windows. To avoid issues you can set Windows system partition as read only and shared drives as read/write.